# Custom lightning Component using Lead Object not working for Community user profile in Napili Template

Tags: community, customer-community

I have created a custom lightning component for lead creation.When I log in as customer community user I cannot see this component whereas when i log in as system administrator I can see this component in the component.the Template is Napili.Is it like for customer community plus license we will not be able to show lead fields?As the same is working when I refer some other object.

Actually this line is causing problem in the lightning component

Please let me know if there are any workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer Community and Customer Community Plus licenses don't have access to Leads.  Partner licenses do.

Do you see the issue if you try with a case?

Comment: No I don't see the issue with case